# mvc get images from model and display

Tags: image, model-view-controller

Can anyone tell me how can I display an image from a list from the model.

This is my code at the moment just trying to get the image from the path.

```
<table>

<% foreach (var item in Model.getLeagues) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div class="leagueImage">
            <img src="../../leagueImages/<%: item.image %>" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.getLeagues) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="leagueImage">
                <img src="~/leagueImages/<%: item.image %>" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```